# check file revision through http only

Tags: svn, http, version-control

If an svn repository is exposed through, say, `http://svn` to users, and there's a file called `script.sh`, is there a way one can get the latest revision number of `script.sh` just through http access?

I'm looking for a specific URL syntax.  Something along the lines of `http://svn/rev?script.sh` perhaps?

Thank you.

Comment: This may be better on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

If you access repository through HTTP server, it usually provides you with the latest revision of the file in the repository. The only thing you need is to build your path properly. Let's suppose you have a directory called `scripts` in the root of your repository, which contains the script you need, then your URL will most likely be following:

```
http://<svnserver>/<repo>/scripts/script.sh
```

The actual path will depend on how you configure the HTTP server or its svn module (e.g. `mod_svn` for Apache) to expose the path.

Comment: I think he means the revision number of the file's latest `log` entry.